# Data(Firebase Firestore) is being duplicated during rendering when more data is created

Tags: javascript, firebase

At the moment of rendering, the data is being duplicated as I commented previously, and I believe that it is because I am trying to insert a row adding the class "space" to place space between the data, but I do not know how to do to add that space without the need to duplicate each data that I create at the moment of adding.
This is my code to visualize and render my data that is in Firebase:

```
function renderTable() {
db.collection('xxx').get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // Adds one row to the table for each document
    var row = document.getElementById('tabla-datos').insertRow(-1);
    
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    cell1.innerHTML = doc.data().a;
    cell2.innerHTML = doc.data().b;
    cell3.innerHTML = doc.data().c;
    cell4.innerHTML = doc.data().d;
    cell5.innerHTML = doc.data().e;
    cell6.innerHTML = doc.data().fr;
    cell7.innerHTML = '<a href="#">Ver</a> | <a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delet</a>';
     // Creates a new empty row at the end of the table
     let rows = document.getElementById('tabla-datos').insertRow(-1);

     // Assigns the class "space" to the row
     rows.classList.add("space");
    });
});

}

db.collection("Productos").onSnapshot(function() {
  renderTable();
});
```

This is the code in css to leave a space:

```
tr.space{
    height:10px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
```

I am currently running javascript connected to firebase in case you were wondering.

Comment: On every change, you are adding rows for each item returned by the query. But you aren't checking if they are already in the table or emptying the table first.

Answer (score 0):

With these lines, you are calling your `renderTable()` function whenever the collection is updated (i.e. data is added, removed and/or updated).

```
db.collection("Productos").onSnapshot(function() {
  renderTable();
});
```

But in your `renderTable()` function, you are always inserting a new row into the existing table whether it exists already or not. Additionally, you don't have any code that handles data that was removed from the query's results.

```
db.collection('xxx').get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // Adds one row to the table for each document
    var row = document.getElementById('tabla-datos').insertRow(-1);
    
    // ...
  }
})
```

To correct this, we'll first create a function that adds your DocumentSnapshot to the given table element:

```
function insertRowForDocument(tableEle, docSnap, index = -1) {
  const rowEle = tableEle.insertRow(index);

  const { a, b, c, d, e, fr } = docSnap.data();

  rowEle.insertCell().innerHtml = a;
  rowEle.insertCell().innerHtml = b;
  rowEle.insertCell().innerHtml = c;
  rowEle.insertCell().innerHtml = d;
  rowEle.insertCell().innerHtml = e;
  rowEle.insertCell().innerHtml = fr;
  rowEle.insertCell().innerHtml = '<a href="#">Ver</a> | <a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delet</a>';

  // bind the document's ID to the row
  rowEle.dataset.docId = docSnap.id;

  // return the new row element
  return rowEle;
}
```

Now that we have an insert function, we can create an update function that updates the row element we pass in:

```
function updateRowForDocument(rowEle, docSnap) {
  const { a, b, c, d, e, fr } = docSnap.data();

  rowEle.cells[0].innerHtml = a;
  rowEle.cells[1].innerHtml = b;
  rowEle.cells[2].innerHtml = c;
  rowEle.cells[3].innerHtml = d;
  rowEle.cells[4].innerHtml = e;
  rowEle.cells[5].innerHtml = fr;
  // rowEle.cells[6] won't change
}
```

Instead of calling `CollectionReference#get` in your `renderTable()` function, instead pass in the `QuerySnapshot` from the `onSnapshot` listener. The `QuerySnapshot` object has a handy `docChanges()` method that provides an array of the documents that were added, removed or modified (when a new listener is attached, all the items will have a change type of 'added'). We can use this array to efficiently refresh your table with the updated data.

**Note:** This next code block assumes you have your header row in a `<thead>` element (otherwise weird behaviour ensues).

```
function renderTable(qSnap) {
  // get the table and its current rows
  const tableEle = document.getElementById('tabla-datos'),
    tableBodyEle = tBodies[0];
  const rowEleMap = [...tableBodyEle.rows]
    .reduce(
      (idRowMap, rowEle) => idRowMap.set(rowEle.dataset.docId, rowEle),
      new Map()
    );

  // update the rows of each document that changed
  qSnap.docChanges()
    .forEach(({ doc, type }) => {
      // find this document's row (if it exists)
      const rowEle = rowEleMap.get(doc.id);

      if (type === 'removed')
        // row to be removed, remove as needed
        return rowEle && rowEle.remove();
      } else if (!rowEle) {
        // row missing, add it to the table and the map
        return idRowMap.set(doc.id, insertRowForDocument(tableEle, doc));
      }

      // row exists already, update it
      updateRowForDocument(rowEle, doc);
    });

  // [sort rows code here (see below)]

  // Now find the spacing row (if it exists, it doesn't have a `dataset.docId` value)
  let spacingRowEle = rowEleMap.get();
  if (spacingRowEle) {
    // move the spacing row to the bottom of the table
    tableBodyEle.appendChild(spacingRowEle);
  } else {
    // create and append a new spacing row
    spacingRowEle = tableEle.insertRow();
    spacingRowEle.classList.add("space");
  }
}
```

You then call it inside your listener like so:

```
const unsubscribe = db.collection("Productos")
  .onSnapshot((qSnap) => {
    renderTable(qSnap);
  });
```

To handle listener errors, you would pass in an observer object:

```
const unsubscribe = db.collection("Productos")
  .onSnapshot({
    next(qSnap) {
      renderTable(qSnap);
    },
    error(err) {
      // placeholder logic, update to something more useful
      console.error("Failed to read /Productos: ", err)
    }
  });
```

Once the above block has been executed and until you call `unsubscribe()`, your table should be kept in sync with your database. Any changes to your documents should be reflected in the table. Currently, the rows of the table will not be sorted and will be added as each new document is added to the server. This means that the order may not be the same upon refreshing the page.

**Note:** Sorting/removing rows from the table may not be desired as it may cause a user to misclick a row if it gets moved from underneath their cursor.

When a document is removed by the server, instead of removing its row immediately, you could create a `removeRowForDocument` method that adds a `deleted` class to the row (that greys it out), adds a "deleted on server" message, and updates the action links to `Restore` (undelete the document) and `Remove` (removes row from table). Then when the user refreshes the page or clicks a "refresh table" button, remove any deleted rows from the table.

To sort the table, you can insert the following lines into the `renderTable` function to sort the rows after updating them:

**Note:** This sort algorithm is not the most efficient but functions fine with small row counts. This sort algorithm also doesn't handle when rows are marked deleted rather than actually removed from the table.

```
// for each document's row, in the order returned by the query, 
// move it to the end of the table, effectively sorting the table
qSnap.forEach(doc => {
  const rowEle = rowEleMap.get(doc.id);
  rowEle && tableBodyEle.appendChild(rowEle);
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I see that if I was missing several things and I had not managed them, with reason I duplicated every time I rendered, thank you very much!